# Mine Sweeper - getting all cells until they neighbor with a bomb

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform the function where i click on a cell , and if it isn't in proximity of a bomb, it'll reveal all up until those who neighbour with a bomb.

I'm practically stuck :

I'm adding the code i think relevant here

```
//Click cells to reveal + placing mines for the first time
function cellClicked(elCell, i, j) {
  if (!gGame.isOn) return;
  if (gClickCounter === 0) {
    getRandomMine(gLevel.mines, i, j);
    startTimeInterval();
    gClickCounter++;
  }
  var cell = gBoard[i][j];
  console.log('cell:', cell);

  if (cell.isShown) return;
  if (!cell.isShown) {
    cell.isShown = true;
    elCell.classList.add('shown');
    gGame.shownCount++;
    console.log('gGame.shownCount:', gGame.shownCount);
  }
  if (cell.isMine === true) {
    gLivesLeft--;
    var elLives = document.querySelector('.lives');
    elLives.innerHTML = gLivesLeft;
    elCell.innerText = BOMB;
    if (gLivesLeft === 0) {
      gameOver();
    }
  } else {
    var gNegs = countNegs(i, j);
    elCell.innerText = gNegs;
    console.log('elCell:', elCell.dataset.i);
    console.log('elCell:', elCell.dataset.j);

    cell.minesAroundCount = gNegs;
    if (gNegs === 0) {
      //check up
      if (i > 0) {
        var uCell = document.getElementById(gBoard.length * (i - 1) + j);
        if (!gBoard[i - 1][j].isShown && !gBoard[i - 1][j].isMarked) {
          cellClicked(uCell, i - 1, j);
        }
      }
      //check down
      if (i < gBoard.length - 1) {
        var uCell = document.getElementById(gBoard.length * (i + 1) + j);
        if (!gBoard[i + 1][j].isShown && !gBoard[i + 1][j].isMarked) {
          cellClicked(uCell, i + 1, j);
        }
      }

      //check right
      if (j < gBoard.length - 1) {
        var uCell = document.getElementById(gBoard.length * i + (j + 1));
        if (!gBoard[i][j + 1].isShown && !gBoard[i][j + 1].isMarked) {
          cellClicked(uCell, i, j + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
//counting neighbors
function countNegs(cellI, cellJ) {
  var negsCount = 0;
  for (var i = cellI - 1; i <= cellI + 1; i++) {
    if (i < 0 || i > gBoard.length - 1) continue;
    for (var j = cellJ - 1; j <= cellJ + 1; j++) {
      if (j < 0 || j > gBoard[i].length - 1) continue;
      if (i === cellI && j === cellJ) continue;

      if (gBoard[i][j].isMine) {
        negsCount++;
      }
      if (negsCount === 0) {
      }
    }
  }
  return negsCount;
}
```

and the entire code is here :
https://codepen.io/Aegtar/pen/XWaLLzz

Would appreciate any life savers here!

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Does it do anything?

Comment: "I'm practically stuck" - What are you stuck with? What's not working?

Comment: The problem is that it randomly disables clicking other cells that are in proximity to bombs and does not reveal any cell.